# AutiHotKey Some key combinations are not intercepted (ex 3,4,5)

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, remap

I want to remap the keyboard in the following mode:

```
2::ctrl
3::shift
4::alt
5::tab
```

My problem is that pressing at the same time 3,4,5 (equivalent to pressing alt shift tab) does not work.
After investigating a little I have found that ahk can not catch some keys when being pressed together (2,3,e OR 3,4,5). Here is my code through which I have found out this

```
2::
    tooltip 2
    sleep 500
    tooltip
return
3::
    tooltip 3
    sleep 500
    tooltip
return
4::
    tooltip 4
    sleep 500
    tooltip
return
5::
    tooltip 5
    sleep 500
    tooltip
return
e::
    tooltip e
    sleep 500
    tooltip
return
```

Anyone knows of a workaround to catch multiple key presses (like 2,3,e OR 3,4,5) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your first code (the remapping) works faultlessly on my system. Something else is wrong in your script or your system. Try it first of all as a stand-alone script.

Comment: I have tried it as a stand alone script and same result, you mean that while pressing 3,4,5  the behaviour is the same as alt shit tab (not alt tab?). If so, what windows and ahk version you using ?

Comment: I have tested it on Win7 and Win10 both 64bit. 3-4-5 is the same as alt-shift-tab. Maybe your keyboard driver needs to be updated.

Comment: strange I have also tested on multiple PCs and the keyboard drivers are up to date, if you have time, could you please also test to see if 2+3+e works (ctrl+shift+e as a hotkey)

Comment: After some experimenting with 3 old keyboards (not MS or Logitech), I found out that your code only works  with my standard keyboard MS Digital Media Keyboard 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a limitation of your keyboard - some keyboards can't handle particular combinations of three keys, which is known as "key jamming."  See the "Key jamming and ghosting" section in the [Rollover (key)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) page on Wikipedia.