# AutoHotKey does not recognize AltGr+Alt+Y

Tags: autohotkey

Most of the keys work in combination with AltGr+Alt+[key]. The not working exceptions I found are y and . (period). I am following this instruction (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys Step 1 to 5) in order to analyze the problem.

Log output for AltGr+Alt+x (my AHK script is working with that shortcut)

```
A2  01D     d   11.34   LControl
A5  138     d   0.00    RAlt            
A4  038     d   0.13    LAlt            
58  02D     d   0.20    x               
58  02D     u   0.13    x               
A2  01D     u   0.17    LControl        
A5  138     u   0.00    RAlt            
A4  038     u   0.00    LAlt
```

Log output for AltGr+Alt+y (my AHK script is NOT working with that short cut)

```
A2  01D     d   1.89    LControl        
A5  138     d   0.00    RAlt            
A4  038     d   0.05    LAlt            
A2  01D     u   0.36    LControl        
A5  138     u   0.00    RAlt            
A4  038     u   0.06    LAlt
```

This log output leads me to believe, that the problem is not my script, but something more global. It seems that AHK is not even receiving the key stroke for "y".

Log output for AltGr+y to prove that my keyboard isn't defective :)

```
A2  01D     d   10.27   LControl
A5  138     d   0.00    RAlt            
59  02C     d   0.23    y               
59  02C     u   0.13    y               
A2  01D     u   0.17    LControl        
A5  138     u   0.00    RAlt
```

Can any of you reproduce this? How can I use AltGr+Alt+Y as a shortcut?
I am using Win10 x64 and AHK Version 1.1.30.01.

**Edit**

Obviously, the issue is only on my computer. So I would like to change the question slightly into: **How can I identify and eliminate the reason that blocks some hotkeys?** Remember that AltGr+Alt+Y is not the only hotkey that does not work, also AltGr+Alt+. and AltGr+Alt+O and possibly more that I have not tested yet.

Comment: The source is here if you want to debug it https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L

Comment: Try   `~<^>!<!y:: MsgBox, LAlt+AltGr+y` (works this way on my system)

Comment: @user3419297: Your script is not working on my system :(. How can I find out what is blocking it?

Comment: Maybe because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991717/3419297).

Comment: So you are basically saying it is the keyboards fault. And indeed, I tested another keyboard and AltGr+Alt+Y is working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of AltGr+LAlt+Key or AltGr+RControl+Key which may cause issues in some programs or key jamming, you can use any other key in place of LAlt or RControl this way:

```
LControl & RAlt:: AltGr := true ; assign the boolean value "true" to the variable 'AltGr''
LControl & RAlt Up:: AltGr := false

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings
#If (AltGr) ; If this variable has the value "true" 

    a:: MsgBox AltGr+a
    a & b:: MsgBox AltGr+a+b
    b & a:: MsgBox AltGr+b+a

    h & l:: Send Hello

    i & e:: Run iexplore.exe
    n & p:: Run notepad
    w & p:: Run wordpad 

#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: It seems that this solution is the closest I can have without dropping my favorit keybord or changing the desired key combination. As a comment for other readers: The posted script is working, because not all keys have to be pressed at the same time. So first press Alt+Ctrl; then release Ctrl while holding Alt and press the additional key(s).