# Remap `AltGr & someKey`

Tags: autohotkey

How do I remap e.g. `AltGr + i`?

I know how to remap other combinations like `alt + i` (`!i::Send, test`) or `shift + i` (`+i::Send, test`). But this doesn't work for `AltGr`.

I know how to map `AltGr` isolated: `LControl & RAlt::Send, test` works. But `LControl & RAlt & i::Send, test` doesn't work.

So, how do I go about it?

**EDIT: SOLVED**
[This solution worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980527/7123519)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the post that OP linked:

Use a context sensitive `#IF` statement to check whether AltGr is held down, then create a standard one-button hotkey.

@[user3419297](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3419297/user3419297)'s example:

```
LControl & RAlt:: AltGr := true ; assign the boolean value "true" to the variable 'AltGr''
LControl & RAlt Up:: AltGr := false

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings
#If (AltGr) ; If this variable has the value "true" 

    a:: MsgBox AltGr+a
    a & b:: MsgBox AltGr+a+b
    b & a:: MsgBox AltGr+b+a

    h & l:: Send Hello

    i & e:: Run iexplore.exe
    n & p:: Run notepad
    w & p:: Run wordpad 

#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```

---

So for OP's specific question:

```
#If (AltGr)
   i::Send, test
#If
```

More info: [Context Sensative #IF statements](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)